# SonarQube false positive squid:S1450 for @Getter (lombok) annotated fields

Tags: java, sonarqube, lombok

I think I have found a false positive while using the [`@Getter`](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) annotation from [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/).

In the following example class I got the warning *"Private fields only used as local variables in methods should become local variables"* ([`squid:S1450`](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS1450)).

```
public class Example {

    @Getter
    private String exampleField; // <-- squid:S1450

    public Example(final String value) {
        setExampleField(value);
    }

    private void setExampleField(final String exampleField) {
        this.exampleField = exampleField;
    }

}
```

Can someone confirm this? Is it a bug in the SonarQube rule or is there something wrong with my class or with my understanding of this rule or the `@Getter` annotation?

Just for the sake of completeness:

- Project lombok annotations or the generated methods are recognized correctly in other SonarQube rules. So I think my setup is fine.
- I have also tried to put the `@Getter` annotation on class level and I got the same warning.
- The warning is shown in SonarLint (in IntelliJ IDEA) and in the web interface of SonarQube. So I think it's not an error while executing the analyzer.
- I have bound the SonarLint pluign in IntelliJ IDEA to our SonarQube Server and this remote connection works.

I have tested with the following versions:

- SonarQube 6.0
- SonarQube Java Plugin 4.2
- SonarLint (for IntelliJ IDEA) 2.3.2
- IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5
- Java 8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right and I've created the following Jira ticket https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1924. Thanks for your feedback !